# 'Pasillo' vs 'corredor' - meaning and usage

Tags: diferencias-regionales, sinónimos, diferencias-entre-palabras

WordReference on [corridor](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=corridor) says that it may be expressed in Spanish by "pasillo" or "corredor", but I have never heard the latter in South America.

Is "corredor" usual in any Spanish-speaking country (eg Spain)?

Is there any difference in meaning between both words?

Comment: At least in Argentina, "pasillo" is more informal than "corredor", which can also be used in other contexts, like "corredor vial" (road corridor). I'm only writing a comment because I don't have more information for a decent reply.

Comment: Also, "pasillo" is always indoor, while "corredor" can be outdoor, as shown above and in the case of "corredor seguro", a system implemented for schoolchildren to follow a safe way back home.

Comment: Even in English, "corridor" is more formal.  I think it is a similar situation in Spanish.

Comment: off-topic: in Portuguese, it is the opposite: "corredor" is the usual word.

Comment: @aparente001 in the dialect of English spoken in South East England corridor is the usual word so this must be subject to regional variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you specifically mention Spain, this answer is about the usage in Spain.

To refer to a small corridor inside a building, such as in a house or in an office building, the word "pasillo" is much more commonly used.

The word "corredor" is sometimes used to refer to much larger corridors, either indoors (maybe at an airport) or most commonly outdoors. For example, the corridors around a courtyard might be called "corredores". There are also several figurative uses of this meaning of the word "corredor", such as the names of some large geographical entities with a similar shape (Corredor del Henares, or several other examples [here](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corredor#Territorio) under "Territorio") or even "corredor de la muerte", which means "death row" .

Comment: I always hear about the 'Corredor del Mediterráneo'